# Javascript High Charts changing Rec Rill hover color

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

On my change I've changed the contentButton like this:

```
exporting: {
    buttons: {
        contextButton: {
            symbol: 'url(newimage.png)',
            y: 6.5,
            menuItems: Highcharts.defaultOptions.exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems.slice(0,7)
        }
    }
},
```

My problem is that when I hover over it there's a

```
<rect fill="#e6e6e6" ...
```

that's appearing is the wrong color.

This is added by highcharts so...

How can I change the color of that fill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it by setting `theme.states.hover.fill` property.

```
 contextButton: {
                theme: {
                  states: {
                    hover: {
                      fill: 'black'
                    }
                  }
                }
            }
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/b6ch8z5x/

#### Update

It is also possible to edit `select` state which is activated when the button is pressed.

```
theme: {
                  states: {
                    select: {
                      fill: 'blue'
                    } 
                  }
                }
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/b6ch8z5x/4/

Other options are listed under [navigation.buttonOptions](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/navigation.buttonOptions) in API docs.

Comment: Almost perfect but when the menu is showing it's grey around...are there's other states apart from hover too?

Comment: Yes, there is a select state - see my updated answer.